# Combobox items from mysql query refresh each second

Tags: c#, mysql, timer, combobox, duplicates

I have combobox items to display date of draw. Items are imported from mysql data. I use this code to get them:

```
        DataTable dateDraw = new DataTable("dateDraw");
        using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(@"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=toor"))
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT date FROM sqldata.datedraw WHERE active='Yes'", sqlConn))
            {
                da.Fill(dateDraw);
            }
        }
        foreach (DataRow da in dateDraw.Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(da[0].ToString());
        }
```

I need items to refresh every second. So I created timer and place code into timer. Set timer.enable to true and interval to 1000. The refresh part works OK. But I get multiple items with same results duplicating on each mysql query.

If mysql first query is for example:

```
12.9.2013
19.9.2013
16.9.2013
```

The second query duplicates it like:

```
12.9.2013
19.9.2013
16.9.2013
12.9.2013
19.9.2013
16.9.2013
```

and the third query:

```
12.9.2013
19.9.2013
16.9.2013
12.9.2013
19.9.2013
16.9.2013
12.9.2013
19.9.2013
16.9.2013
```

and so on.

How to remove duplicate results?

Thank you.

I am looking for solution I will understand because I am a noob. Thanks!

Comment: Do a `comboBox1.Items.Clear();` right before you add new items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear comboBox before adding items, Am I missing something?

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

add

```
  comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

before

```
  foreach (DataRow da in dateDraw.Rows)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(da[0].ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding them row by row, you could use

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = dateDraw.Rows
```

You can set seperately which fields in those rows should be used for display and as (key)value setting `combobox1.DisplayMember` and `combobox1.Datamember` respectively

Apart from that, as a user i might get homocidal intension towards the programmer if i am selecting something from a combobox, and that combobox goes empty and refills, probably making my selection disappear - if I ever manage to make a selection at all!